# talend: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM error='Cannot allocate memory' (errno=12)

Tags: ubuntu, amazon-ec2, java-8, talend, ubuntu-server

I was trying to run talend open studio for data integration on Ubuntu server(headless) in AWS, while opening talend it’s throwing an error:

```
> Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: INFO:
> os::commit_memory(0x00000000a0000000, 536870912, 0) failed;
> error='Cannot allocate memory' (errno=12)
>     #
>     # There is insufficient memory for the Java Runtime Environment to continue.
>     # Native memory allocation (mmap) failed to map 536870912 bytes for committing reserved memory.
>     # An error report file with more information is saved as:
>     # /home/ubuntu/hs_err_pid25954.log
>     X11 connection rejected because of wrong authentication.
>     TOS_DI-linux-gtk-x86_64: Cannot open display:
>     TOS_DI-linux-gtk-x86_64:
>     JVM terminated. Exit code=1
>     /usr/bin/java
>     -Xms512m
>     -Xmx1536m
>     -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
>     -Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.8
>     -XX:+UseG1GC
>     -XX:+UseStringDeduplication
>     -Dorg.eclipse.swt.browser.XULRunnerPath=/usr/local/lib/xulrunner
>     -jar /usr/local/TOS_DI-20161216_1026-V6.3.1/plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20140415-2008.jar
>     -os linux
>     -ws gtk
>     -arch x86_64
>     -showsplash
>     -launcher /usr/local/TOS_DI-20161216_1026-V6.3.1/TOS_DI-linux-gtk-x86_64
>     -name TOS_DI-linux-gtk-x86_64
>     --launcher.library /usr/local/TOS_DI-20161216_1026-V6.3.1/plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.gtk.linux.x86_64_1.1.200.v20140603-1326/eclipse_1605.so
>     -startup /usr/local/TOS_DI-20161216_1026-V6.3.1/plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20140415-2008.jar
>     --launcher.overrideVmargs
>     -exitdata 140009
>     -vm /usr/bin/java
>     -vmargs
>     -Xms512m
>     -Xmx1536m
>     -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
>     -Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.8
>     -XX:+UseG1GC
>     -XX:+UseStringDeduplication
>     -Dorg.eclipse.swt.browser.XULRunnerPath=/usr/local/lib/xulrunner
>     -jar /usr/local/TOS_DI-20161216_1026-V6.3.1/plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20140415-2008.jar
>     rudder@ip-172-31-0-45:/home/ubuntu$ "/usr/local/TOS_DI-20161216_1026-V6.3.1/TOS_DI-linux-gtk-x86_64"
>     Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: INFO: os::commit_memory(0x00000000a0000000, 536870912, 0) failed;
> error='Cannot allocate memory' (errno=12)
>     #
>     # There is insufficient memory for the Java Runtime Environment to continue.
>     # Native memory allocation (mmap) failed to map 536870912 bytes for committing reserved memory.
>     # An error report file with more information is saved as:
>     # /tmp/hs_err_pid25972.log
>     X11 connection rejected because of wrong authentication.
>     TOS_DI-linux-gtk-x86_64: Cannot open display:
>     TOS_DI-linux-gtk-x86_64:
>     JVM terminated. Exit code=1
>     /usr/bin/java
>     -Xms512m
>     -Xmx1536m
>     -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
>     -Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.8
>     -XX:+UseG1GC
>     -XX:+UseStringDeduplication
>     -Dorg.eclipse.swt.browser.XULRunnerPath=/usr/local/lib/xulrunner
>     -jar /usr/local/TOS_DI-20161216_1026-V6.3.1/plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20140415-2008.jar
>     -os linux
>     -ws gtk
>     -arch x86_64
>     -showsplash
>     -launcher /usr/local/TOS_DI-20161216_1026-V6.3.1/TOS_DI-linux-gtk-x86_64
>     -name TOS_DI-linux-gtk-x86_64
>     --launcher.library /usr/local/TOS_DI-20161216_1026-V6.3.1/plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.gtk.linux.x86_64_1.1.200.v20140603-1326/eclipse_1605.so
>     -startup /usr/local/TOS_DI-20161216_1026-V6.3.1/plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20140415-2008.jar
>     --launcher.overrideVmargs
>     -exitdata 148009
>     -vm /usr/bin/java
>     -vmargs
>     -Xms512m
>     -Xmx1536m
>     -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
>     -Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.8
>     -XX:+UseG1GC
>     -XX:+UseStringDeduplication
>     -Dorg.eclipse.swt.browser.XULRunnerPath=/usr/local/lib/xulrunner
>     -jar /usr/local/TOS_DI-20161216_1026-V6.3.1/plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20140415-2008.jar
```

generated log file:

```
>     #
>     # There is insufficient memory for the Java Runtime Environment to continue.
>     # Native memory allocation (mmap) failed to map 536870912 bytes for committing reserved memory.
>     # Possible reasons:
>     #   The system is out of physical RAM or swap space
>     #   In 32 bit mode, the process size limit was hit
>     # Possible solutions:
>     #   Reduce memory load on the system
>     #   Increase physical memory or swap space
>     #   Check if swap backing store is full
>     #   Use 64 bit Java on a 64 bit OS
>     #   Decrease Java heap size (-Xmx/-Xms)
>     #   Decrease number of Java threads
>     #   Decrease Java thread stack sizes (-Xss)
>     #   Set larger code cache with -XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=
>     # This output file may be truncated or incomplete.
>     #
>     #  Out of Memory Error (os_linux.cpp:2627), pid=25954, tid=0x00007f7d53665700
>     #
>     # JRE version:  (8.0_121-b13) (build )
>     # Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (25.121-b13 mixed mode linux-amd64 compressed oops)
>     # Failed to write core dump. Core dumps have been disabled. To enable core dumping, try "ulimit -c unlimited" before starting Java
> again
>     #
>     
>     ---------------  T H R E A D  ---------------
>     
>     Current thread (0x00007f7d4c00b000):  JavaThread "Unknown thread" [_thread_in_vm, id=25955,
> stack(0x00007f7d53565000,0x00007f7d53666000)]
>     
>     Stack: [0x00007f7d53565000,0x00007f7d53666000],  sp=0x00007f7d53663e50,  free space=1019k
>     Native frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code, C=native code)
>     V  [libjvm.so+0xac703a]  VMError::report_and_die()+0x2ba
>     V  [libjvm.so+0x4fc7eb]  report_vm_out_of_memory(char const*, int, unsigned long, VMErrorType, char const*)+0x8b
>     V  [libjvm.so+0x923c43]  os::Linux::commit_memory_impl(char*, unsigned long, bool)+0x103
>     V  [libjvm.so+0x9240e5]  os::pd_commit_memory_or_exit(char*, unsigned long, unsigned long, bool, char const*)+0x35
>     V  [libjvm.so+0x91e1c6]  os::commit_memory_or_exit(char*, unsigned long, unsigned long, bool, char const*)+0x26
>     V  [libjvm.so+0x5c378f]  G1PageBasedVirtualSpace::commit_internal(unsigned long, unsigned
> long)+0xbf
>     V  [libjvm.so+0x5c3a1c]  G1PageBasedVirtualSpace::commit(unsigned long, unsigned long)+0x11c
>     V  [libjvm.so+0x5c6700]  G1RegionsLargerThanCommitSizeMapper::commit_regions(unsigned int,
> unsigned long)+0x40
>     V  [libjvm.so+0x629d67]  HeapRegionManager::commit_regions(unsigned int, unsigned long)+0x77
>     V  [libjvm.so+0x62b001]  HeapRegionManager::make_regions_available(unsigned int, unsigned
> int)+0x31
>     V  [libjvm.so+0x62b580]  HeapRegionManager::expand_by(unsigned int)+0xb0
>     V  [libjvm.so+0x59a919]  G1CollectedHeap::expand(unsigned long)+0x199
>     V  [libjvm.so+0x5a0c15]  G1CollectedHeap::initialize()+0x895
>     V  [libjvm.so+0xa8eff3]  Universe::initialize_heap()+0xf3
>     V  [libjvm.so+0xa8f55e]  universe_init()+0x3e
>     V  [libjvm.so+0x63d4f5]  init_globals()+0x65
>     V  [libjvm.so+0xa72c4e]  Threads::create_vm(JavaVMInitArgs*, bool*)+0x23e
>     V  [libjvm.so+0x6d1d94]  JNI_CreateJavaVM+0x74
>     C  [libjli.so+0x745e]  JavaMain+0x9e
>     C  [libpthread.so.0+0x76ba]  start_thread+0xca
>     
>     
>     ---------------  P R O C E S S  ---------------
>     
>     Java Threads: ( => current thread )
>     
>     Other Threads:
>     
>     =>0x00007f7d4c00b000 (exited) JavaThread "Unknown thread" [_thread_in_vm, id=25955,
> stack(0x00007f7d53565000,0x00007f7d53666000)]
>     
>     VM state:not at safepoint (not fully initialized)
>     
>     VM Mutex/Monitor currently owned by a thread:  ([mutex/lock_event])
>     [0x00007f7d4c007640] Heap_lock - owner thread: 0x00007f7d4c00b000
>     
>     GC Heap History (0 events):
>     No events
>     
>     Deoptimization events (0 events):
>     No events
>     
>     Internal exceptions (0 events):
>     No events
>     
>     Events (0 events):
>     No events
>     
>     
>     Dynamic libraries:
>     00400000-00401000 r-xp 00000000 ca:01 157190                             /usr/local/java/jdk1.8.0_121/jre/bin/java
>     00600000-00601000 rw-p 00000000 ca:01 157190                             /usr/local/java/jdk1.8.0_121/jre/bin/java
>     01026000-01047000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                                  [heap]
>     c0000000-100000000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
>     7f7d24000000-7f7d24021000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
>     7f7d24021000-7f7d28000000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
>     7f7d2a000000-7f7d2c000000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
>     7f7d2c000000-7f7d2c021000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
>     7f7d2c021000-7f7d30000000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
>     7f7d30000000-7f7d30021000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
>     7f7d30021000-7f7d34000000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
>     7f7d34d68000-7f7d35000000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
>     7f7d35000000-7f7d38000000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
>     7f7d38000000-7f7d38021000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
>     7f7d38021000-7f7d3c000000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
>     7f7d3c00d000-7f7d3c0fd000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
>     7f7d3c0fd000-7f7d3c0fe000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
>     7f7d3c0fe000-7f7d3c1fe000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
>     7f7d3c1fe000-7f7d3c1ff000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
>     7f7d3c1ff000-7f7d3c2ff000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
>     7f7d3c2ff000-7f7d3ceff000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
>     7f7d3ceff000-7f7d3cf00000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
>     7f7d3cf00000-7f7d3d000000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
>     7f7d3d000000-7f7d3d270000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0 
>     7f7d3d270000-7f7d4c000000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
>     7f7d4c000000-7f7d4c060000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
>     7f7d4c060000-7f7d50000000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
>     7f7d50002000-7f7d50003000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
>     7f7d50003000-7f7d50204000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
>     7f7d50204000-7f7d50205000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
>     7f7d50205000-7f7d5030f000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
>     7f7d5030f000-7f7d506c5000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
>     7f7d506c5000-7f7d506df000 r-xp 00000000 ca:01 157023                     /usr/local/java/jdk1.8.0_121/jre/lib/amd64/libzip.so
>     7f7d506df000-7f7d508df000 ---p 0001a000 ca:01 157023                     /usr/local/java/jdk1.8.0_121/jre/lib/amd64/libzip.so
>     7f7d508df000-7f7d508e0000 rw-p 0001a000 ca:01 157023                     /usr/local/java/jdk1.8.0_121/jre/lib/amd64/libzip.so
>     7f7d508e0000-7f7d508eb000 r-xp 00000000 ca:01 396940                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnss_files-2.23.so
>     7f7d508eb000-7f7d50aea000 ---p 0000b000 ca:01 396940                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnss_files-2.23.so
>     7f7d50aea000-7f7d50aeb000 r--p 0000a000 ca:01 396940                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnss_files-2.23.so
>     7f7d50aeb000-7f7d50aec000 rw-p 0000b000 ca:01 396940                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnss_files-2.23.so
>     7f7d50aec000-7f7d50af2000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
>     7f7d50af2000-7f7d50afd000 r-xp 00000000 ca:01 396942                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnss_nis-2.23.so
>     7f7d50afd000-7f7d50cfc000 ---p 0000b000 ca:01 396942                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnss_nis-2.23.so
>     7f7d50cfc000-7f7d50cfd000 r--p 0000a000 ca:01 396942                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnss_nis-2.23.so
>     7f7d50cfd000-7f7d50cfe000 rw-p 0000b000 ca:01 396942                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnss_nis-2.23.so
>     7f7d50cfe000-7f7d50d14000 r-xp 00000000 ca:01 396937                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnsl-2.23.so
>     7f7d50d14000-7f7d50f13000 ---p 00016000 ca:01 396937                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnsl-2.23.so
>     7f7d50f13000-7f7d50f14000 r--p 00015000 ca:01 396937                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnsl-2.23.so
>     7f7d50f14000-7f7d50f15000 rw-p 00016000 ca:01 396937                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnsl-2.23.so
>     7f7d50f15000-7f7d50f17000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
>     7f7d50f17000-7f7d50f1f000 r-xp 00000000 ca:01 396938                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnss_compat-2.23.so
>     7f7d50f1f000-7f7d5111e000 ---p 00008000 ca:01 396938                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnss_compat-2.23.so
>     7f7d5111e000-7f7d5111f000 r--p 00007000 ca:01 396938                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnss_compat-2.23.so
>     7f7d5111f000-7f7d51120000 rw-p 00008000 ca:01 396938                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnss_compat-2.23.so
>     7f7d51120000-7f7d5114b000 r-xp 00000000 ca:01 157050                     /usr/local/java/jdk1.8.0_121/jre/lib/amd64/libjava.so
>     7f7d5114b000-7f7d5134a000 ---p 0002b000 ca:01 157050                     /usr/local/java/jdk1.8.0_121/jre/lib/amd64/libjava.so
>     7f7d5134a000-7f7d5134c000 rw-p 0002a000 ca:01 157050                     /usr/local/java/jdk1.8.0_121/jre/lib/amd64/libjava.so
>     7f7d5134c000-7f7d51359000 r-xp 00000000 ca:01 157001                     /usr/local/java/jdk1.8.0_121/jre/lib/amd64/libverify.so
>     7f7d51359000-7f7d51558000 ---p 0000d000 ca:01 157001                     /usr/local/java/jdk1.8.0_121/jre/lib/amd64/libverify.so
>     7f7d51558000-7f7d5155a000 rw-p 0000c000 ca:01 157001                     /usr/local/java/jdk1.8.0_121/jre/lib/amd64/libverify.so
>     7f7d5155a000-7f7d51561000 r-xp 00000000 ca:01 396963                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librt-2.23.so
>     7f7d51561000-7f7d51760000 ---p 00007000 ca:01 396963                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librt-2.23.so
>     7f7d51760000-7f7d51761000 r--p 00006000 ca:01 396963                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librt-2.23.so
>     7f7d51761000-7f7d51762000 rw-p 00007000 ca:01 396963                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librt-2.23.so
>     7f7d51762000-7f7d5186a000 r-xp 00000000 ca:01 396928                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm-2.23.so
>     7f7d5186a000-7f7d51a69000 ---p 00108000 ca:01 396928                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm-2.23.so
>     7f7d51a69000-7f7d51a6a000 r--p 00107000 ca:01 396928                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm-2.23.so
>     7f7d51a6a000-7f7d51a6b000 rw-p 00108000 ca:01 396928                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm-2.23.so
>     7f7d51a6b000-7f7d52739000 r-xp 00000000 ca:01 157054                     /usr/local/java/jdk1.8.0_121/jre/lib/amd64/server/libjvm.so
>     7f7d52739000-7f7d52939000 ---p 00cce000 ca:01 157054                     /usr/local/java/jdk1.8.0_121/jre/lib/amd64/server/libjvm.so
>     7f7d52939000-7f7d52a12000 rw-p 00cce000 ca:01 157054                     /usr/local/java/jdk1.8.0_121/jre/lib/amd64/server/libjvm.so
>     7f7d52a12000-7f7d52a5d000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
>     7f7d52a5d000-7f7d52c1c000 r-xp 00000000 ca:01 396893                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.23.so
>     7f7d52c1c000-7f7d52e1c000 ---p 001bf000 ca:01 396893                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.23.so
>     7f7d52e1c000-7f7d52e20000 r--p 001bf000 ca:01 396893                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.23.so
>     7f7d52e20000-7f7d52e22000 rw-p 001c3000 ca:01 396893                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.23.so
>     7f7d52e22000-7f7d52e26000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
>     7f7d52e26000-7f7d52e29000 r-xp 00000000 ca:01 396904                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl-2.23.so
>     7f7d52e29000-7f7d53028000 ---p 00003000 ca:01 396904                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl-2.23.so
>     7f7d53028000-7f7d53029000 r--p 00002000 ca:01 396904                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl-2.23.so
>     7f7d53029000-7f7d5302a000 rw-p 00003000 ca:01 396904                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl-2.23.so
>     7f7d5302a000-7f7d5303f000 r-xp 00000000 ca:01 157039                     /usr/local/java/jdk1.8.0_121/jre/lib/amd64/jli/libjli.so
>     7f7d5303f000-7f7d5323f000 ---p 00015000 ca:01 157039                     /usr/local/java/jdk1.8.0_121/jre/lib/amd64/jli/libjli.so
>     7f7d5323f000-7f7d53240000 rw-p 00015000 ca:01 157039                     /usr/local/java/jdk1.8.0_121/jre/lib/amd64/jli/libjli.so
>     7f7d53240000-7f7d53258000 r-xp 00000000 ca:01 396959                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread-2.23.so
>     7f7d53258000-7f7d53457000 ---p 00018000 ca:01 396959                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread-2.23.so
>     7f7d53457000-7f7d53458000 r--p 00017000 ca:01 396959                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread-2.23.so
>     7f7d53458000-7f7d53459000 rw-p 00018000 ca:01 396959                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread-2.23.so
>     7f7d53459000-7f7d5345d000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
>     7f7d5345d000-7f7d53483000 r-xp 00000000 ca:01 396881                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.23.so
>     7f7d534a3000-7f7d53565000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
>     7f7d53565000-7f7d53568000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
>     7f7d53568000-7f7d5366a000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
>     7f7d53676000-7f7d5367e000 rw-s 00000000 ca:01 148498                     /tmp/hsperfdata_root/25954
>     7f7d5367e000-7f7d5367f000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
>     7f7d5367f000-7f7d53680000 r--p 00000000 00:00 0 
>     7f7d53680000-7f7d53682000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
>     7f7d53682000-7f7d53683000 r--p 00025000 ca:01 396881                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.23.so
>     7f7d53683000-7f7d53684000 rw-p 00026000 ca:01 396881                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.23.so
>     7f7d53684000-7f7d53685000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
>     7ffe16edb000-7ffe16efc000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                          [stack]
>     7ffe16f34000-7ffe16f36000 r--p 00000000 00:00 0                          [vvar]
>     7ffe16f36000-7ffe16f38000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0                          [vdso]
>     ffffffffff600000-ffffffffff601000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0                  [vsyscall]
>     
>     VM Arguments:
>     jvm_args: -Xms512m -Xmx1536m -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.8 -XX:+UseG1GC -XX:+UseStringDeduplication -Dorg.eclipse.swt.browser.XULRunnerPath=/usr/local/lib/xulrunner 
>     java_command: /usr/local/TOS_DI-20161216_1026-V6.3.1/plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20140415-2008.jar
> -os linux -ws gtk -arch x86_64 -showsplash -launcher /usr/local/TOS_DI-20161216_1026-V6.3.1/TOS_DI-linux-gtk-x86_64 -name
> TOS_DI-linux-gtk-x86_64 --launcher.library
> /usr/local/TOS_DI-20161216_1026-V6.3.1/plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.gtk.linux.x86_64_1.1.200.v20140603-1326/eclipse_1605.so
> -startup /usr/local/TOS_DI-20161216_1026-V6.3.1/plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20140415-2008.jar
> --launcher.overrideVmargs -exitdata 140009 -vm /usr/bin/java -vmargs -Xms512m -Xmx1536m -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.8 -XX:+UseG1GC -XX:+UseStringDeduplication -Dorg.eclipse.swt.browser.XULRunnerPath=/usr/local/lib/xulrunner -jar /usr/local/TOS_DI-20161216_1026-V6.3.1/plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20140415-2008.jar
>     java_class_path (initial): /usr/local/TOS_DI-20161216_1026-V6.3.1/plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20140415-2008.jar
>     Launcher Type: SUN_STANDARD
>     
>     Environment Variables:
>     PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/snap/bin
>     USERNAME=root
>     SHELL=/bin/bash
>     DISPLAY=localhost:10.0
>     
>     Signal Handlers:
>     SIGSEGV: [libjvm.so+0xac78c0], sa_mask[0]=11111111011111111101111111111110,
> sa_flags=SA_RESTART|SA_SIGINFO
>     SIGBUS: [libjvm.so+0xac78c0], sa_mask[0]=11111111011111111101111111111110,
> sa_flags=SA_RESTART|SA_SIGINFO
>     SIGFPE: [libjvm.so+0x920ac0], sa_mask[0]=11111111011111111101111111111110,
> sa_flags=SA_RESTART|SA_SIGINFO
>     SIGPIPE: [libjvm.so+0x920ac0], sa_mask[0]=11111111011111111101111111111110,
> sa_flags=SA_RESTART|SA_SIGINFO
>     SIGXFSZ: [libjvm.so+0x920ac0], sa_mask[0]=11111111011111111101111111111110,
> sa_flags=SA_RESTART|SA_SIGINFO
>     SIGILL: [libjvm.so+0x920ac0], sa_mask[0]=11111111011111111101111111111110,
> sa_flags=SA_RESTART|SA_SIGINFO
>     SIGUSR1: SIG_DFL, sa_mask[0]=00000000000000000000000000000000, sa_flags=none
>     SIGUSR2: [libjvm.so+0x922300], sa_mask[0]=00000000000000000000000000000000,
> sa_flags=SA_RESTART|SA_SIGINFO
>     SIGHUP: SIG_DFL, sa_mask[0]=00000000000000000000000000000000, sa_flags=none
>     SIGINT: SIG_DFL, sa_mask[0]=00000000000000000000000000000000, sa_flags=none
>     SIGTERM: SIG_DFL, sa_mask[0]=00000000000000000000000000000000, sa_flags=none
>     SIGQUIT: SIG_DFL, sa_mask[0]=00000000000000000000000000000000, sa_flags=none
>     
>     
>     ---------------  S Y S T E M  ---------------
>     
>     OS:DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
>     DISTRIB_RELEASE=16.04
>     DISTRIB_CODENAME=xenial
>     DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS"
>     
>     uname:Linux 4.4.0-64-generic #85-Ubuntu SMP Mon Feb 20 11:50:30 UTC 2017 x86_64
>     libc:glibc 2.23 NPTL 2.23 
>     rlimit: STACK 8192k, CORE 0k, NPROC 3906, NOFILE 65536, AS infinity
>     load average:1.22 0.73 0.38
>     
>     /proc/meminfo:
>     MemTotal:        1014372 kB
>     MemFree:          125420 kB
>     MemAvailable:     406328 kB
>     Buffers:          111276 kB
>     Cached:           187860 kB
>     SwapCached:            0 kB
>     Active:           674600 kB
>     Inactive:         129300 kB
>     Active(anon):     507732 kB
>     Inactive(anon):    23404 kB
>     Active(file):     166868 kB
>     Inactive(file):   105896 kB
>     Unevictable:        3656 kB
>     Mlocked:            3656 kB
>     SwapTotal:             0 kB
>     SwapFree:              0 kB
>     Dirty:             11456 kB
>     Writeback:             0 kB
>     AnonPages:        508432 kB
>     Mapped:           118280 kB
>     Shmem:             23940 kB
>     Slab:              47856 kB
>     SReclaimable:      27584 kB
>     SUnreclaim:        20272 kB
>     KernelStack:        4176 kB
>     PageTables:        11444 kB
>     NFS_Unstable:          0 kB
>     Bounce:                0 kB
>     WritebackTmp:          0 kB
>     CommitLimit:      507184 kB
>     Committed_AS:    1566396 kB
>     VmallocTotal:   34359738367 kB
>     VmallocUsed:           0 kB
>     VmallocChunk:          0 kB
>     HardwareCorrupted:     0 kB
>     AnonHugePages:     36864 kB
>     CmaTotal:              0 kB
>     CmaFree:               0 kB
>     HugePages_Total:       0
>     HugePages_Free:        0
>     HugePages_Rsvd:        0
>     HugePages_Surp:        0
>     Hugepagesize:       2048 kB
>     DirectMap4k:       61440 kB
>     DirectMap2M:     1118208 kB
>     
>     
>     CPU:total 1 (1 cores per cpu, 1 threads per core) family 6 model 63 stepping 2, cmov, cx8, fxsr, mmx, sse, sse2, sse3, ssse3, sse4.1,
> sse4.2, popcnt, avx, avx2, aes, clmul, erms, lzcnt, tsc, bmi1, bmi2
>     
>     /proc/cpuinfo:
>     processor : 0
>     vendor_id : GenuineIntel
>     cpu family    : 6
>     model     : 63
>     model name    : Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2676 v3 @ 2.40GHz
>     stepping  : 2
>     microcode : 0x2b
>     cpu MHz       : 2400.052
>     cache size    : 30720 KB
>     physical id   : 0
>     siblings  : 1
>     core id       : 0
>     cpu cores : 1
>     apicid        : 0
>     initial apicid    : 0
>     fpu       : yes
>     fpu_exception : yes
>     cpuid level   : 13
>     wp        : yes
>     flags     : fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush mmx fxsr sse sse2 ht syscall nx rdtscp lm
> constant_tsc rep_good nopl xtopology eagerfpu pni pclmulqdq ssse3 fma
> cx16 pcid sse4_1 sse4_2 x2apic movbe popcnt tsc_deadline_timer aes
> xsave avx f16c rdrand hypervisor lahf_lm abm fsgsbase bmi1 avx2 smep
> bmi2 erms invpcid xsaveopt
>     bugs      :
>     bogomips  : 4800.10
>     clflush size  : 64
>     cache_alignment   : 64
>     address sizes : 46 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
>     power management:
>     
>     
>     
>     Memory: 4k page, physical 1014372k(125420k free), swap 0k(0k free)
>     
>     vm_info: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (25.121-b13) for linux-amd64 JRE (1.8.0_121-b13), built on Dec 12 2016 16:36:53 by
> "java_re" with gcc 4.3.0 20080428 (Red Hat 4.3.0-8)
>     
>     time: Mon Mar 20 16:55:11 2017
>     elapsed time: 0 seconds (0d 0h 0m 0s)
```

I am not able to understand what is the issue. Can anyone tell me how to resolve it?

Comment: I don't know the tool specifically, but the error says you're out of RAM - it's trying to allocate 500MB of memory and can't. Are you on a tiny AWS instance?

Comment: @court3nay Yes we have t2.micro instance on AWS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error says it all:

There is insufficient memory for the Java Runtime Environment to continue.

> ```
> # Native memory allocation (mmap) failed to map 536870912 bytes for committing reserved memory.
> # Possible reasons:
> #   The system is out of physical RAM or swap space
> ```

You're running on a t2.micro, so you only have 1GB of RAM, which is not enough for java. Try a much bigger instance and see how much memory you use, then you can scale down.